How to render templ inside an another templ file
I have boilerplate.templ, navbar.templ and body.templ. How do I embed these templ files in boilerplate?
I tried this:
package views

css Base(){
    background-color: #F4F2F3;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    
}

navbarComponent:=navbar()

templ boilerplate(){
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            {navbarComponent.render(nil,nil)}          
        </body>
    </html>
}

edit:

i am using templ for templating


Please state which templating package you are using (I'd guess templ?). It would also be helpful to include a Minimal, Reproducable, Example (i.e. include two templ basic files and a simple main.go) and tell us what you expect the output to be and what is not working (as you have only given us one file and not indicated what is wrong its difficult to help). See this for a basic example (it does not matter if its split across files).

Ref your update - what is not working? (I have just duplicated this and, as expected, it outputs the content of Boilerplate with the Navbar embedded). Please provide a full example (include your main.go too.

@Brits i found the solution in docs and i just edited and added my solution to the question its working well now

Please dont do that (others may spend time trying to help, as I did). Answering your own quesion is a better approach.

@Brits I apologise, that was my first time asking a question sorry

Here's an example, assuming you're asking about the std lib:
templates/base.html
{{ define "body" }}{{ end }}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
{{ template "body" . }}
</body>

templates/about.html
{{ block "body" . }}
<h1>About page</h1>
{{ end }}

Then you execute the template like this:
//go:embed templates
var files embed.FS

...

    var tmpl *template.Template
    if condForJustAboutPage {
        tmpl = template.Must(template.New("about.html").ParseFS(files, "templates/about.html"))
    } else {
        // return whole page: base + about.
        tmpl = template.Must(template.New("base.html").ParseFS(files, "templates/about.html", "templates/base.html"))
    }

    err := tmpl.Execute(w, "")
    if err != nil {
        // todo handle this
        return
    }

I suggest you take a look at the docs to better understand how blocks work (in [1] just a snippet), and how Nested template definitions work.
Hope this helps!
[1]
{{block "name" pipeline}} T1 {{end}}
    A block is shorthand for defining a template
        {{define "name"}} T1 {{end}}
    and then executing it in place
        {{template "name" pipeline}}
    The typical use is to define a set of root templates that are
    then customized by redefining the block templates within.


found my answer in docs, to nest a templ template inside another i just have to use Prop drilling
https://templ.guide/syntax-and-usage/context
navbar.templ:
package views


templ Navbar( )  {

<nav class="bg-white border-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-900">
  <div class="max-w-screen-xl flex flex-wrap items-center justify-between mx-auto p-4">
    <a href="https://flowbite.com/" class="flex items-center space-x-3 rtl:space-x-reverse">
        <img src="https://flowbite.com/docs/images/logo.svg" class="h-8" alt="Flowbite Logo" />
        <span class="self-center text-2xl font-semibold whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">Title</span>
    </a>
    <button data-collapse-toggle="navbar-default" type="button" class="inline-flex items-center p-2 w-10 h-10 justify-center text-sm text-gray-500 rounded-lg md:hidden hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-gray-200 dark:text-gray-400 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-gray-600" aria-controls="navbar-default" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
        <svg class="w-5 h-5" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 17 14">
            <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M1 1h15M1 7h15M1 13h15"/>
        </svg>
    </button>
    <div class="hidden w-full md:block md:w-auto" id="navbar-default">
      <ul class="font-medium flex flex-col p-4 md:p-0 mt-4 border border-gray-100 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 md:flex-row md:space-x-8 rtl:space-x-reverse md:mt-0 md:border-0 md:bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 md:dark:bg-gray-900 dark:border-gray-700">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-3 text-white bg-blue-700 rounded md:bg-transparent md:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-white md:dark:text-blue-500" aria-current="page">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-white md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent">Encode</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="block py-2 px-3 text-gray-900 rounded hover:bg-gray-100 md:hover:bg-transparent md:border-0 md:hover:text-blue-700 md:p-0 dark:text-white md:dark:hover:text-blue-500 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:hover:text-white md:dark:hover:bg-transparent">Decode</a>
        </li>
        
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

}

to nest navbar in my boilerplate:
boilerplate.templ:
package views


templ Boilerplate(){

    <html>
        <head>
            
            <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            @Navbar()    
        </body>
    </html>
}


